Can Nginx pass through PROXY protocol destination address/port?
We have Nginx running as a TCP proxy configured to receive PROXY protocol data from a downstream load balancer and send PROXY protocol data to an upstream server:
stream {
    server {
        listen 12345 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}

The upstream server is configured to receive the PROXY protocol data from Nginx; the PROXY protocol source IP address/port that the upstream server receives is the client's source IP address/port however the destination IP address/port is Nginx server address/port.
Is it possible to configure Nginx to send the client's destination address/port in the PROXY protocol data? In other words, can Nginx be configured to pass through or forward the PROXY protocol data received from the load balancer to the upstream server so that the upstream server knows the client's source address/port and destination address/port?

what is the business related question in here? What is the business related problem you are working on?

It's difficult to give all the context, but the upstream application is using the PROXY protocol destination port in the location HTTP response header, redirecting the client to an incorrect port on the load balancer (i.e. the Nginx serving port is different to the load balancer serving port). Of course, changing the upstream application to not do this would be one way to fix this, but the owner of the application doesn't know how to do that. Also, we cannot change the Nginx or load balancer serving ports as this would break other applications

and the application is totally unknown or why will it be hidden in here? however I don't see here any relevant research but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493170/nginx-forward-requests-to-another-proxy someone already asked it
